# How to find the oldest file in given directory in Windows CMD?

Tags: windows, batch, script, batch-file

I'm trying to delete the oldest file in  a given path VIA batch file.
My code:

```
@echo on
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set source = C:\Users\tzahi.k\Desktop\scripts\testSource\source

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir %source% /a-d /b /o-d ')  do set oldest=%%a >> del_oldest_log.txt
```

This chooses every file in the folder.
What am I doing wrong?
Help :-)

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23598102/348694).

Answer (score 1):

got it....

```
@echo on
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

forfiles -p "sourcePath" -s -m *.* /D -7 /C "cmd /c del @path"  >> log/log.txt
```

it's delete all files older then 7 days ago

Comment: That's not what you've asked for (but it may work for you). The linked post offers the correct solution. In your `for` loop, the last (and oldest) output will overwrite younger entries. Just assign it in the loop, then after the loop `echo` it to the logfile and use it to delete the oldest file. Or sort oldest files first, and leave the loop logging and deleting with an `goto`.